# Why does this leak in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

Why does the following code leak?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var item = {};
    item.elem = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(item.elem);
    item.addEvent = function(name,listener) {
        var self = this;
        var wrappedListener = function() {
            return listener.apply(self,arguments);
        }
        //Uh-oh creating a circular reference here!
        //The wrappedListener has a closure on self and therefore on item.elem.
        addEvent(this.elem,name,wrappedListener);
        return wrappedListener;
    }
    var wrap = item.addEvent('eventName',listen);

    //Now remove the eventHandler - this should free up the circular reference.
    removeEvent(item.elem, 'eventName', wrap);
    if (item.elem.parentNode) {
        item.elem.parentNode.removeChild(item.elem);
    }
    //item.elem = null; //With this also un-commented, the leak disappears.
    //The fact that I have to null item.elem tells me that something is holding
    //a reference to item, and therefore elem. Setting elem to null fixes the
    //problem, but since I am removing the event handler, I don't think this
    //should be required.
}
```

Note: `addEvent` and `removeEvent` are just to abstract `attachEvent`/`addEventListener` differences between Internet Explorer and other browsers.

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) project which demonstrates the problem. Just fire up Internet Explorer 8 and watch it go in Task Manager or Process Explorer. Also, you will see the definition of `addEvent` and `removeEvent` there.

http://jsfiddle.net/rJ8x5/34/

EDIT: Well, I came up with the following solution. It is not pretty, but it works!
http://jsfiddle.net/rJ8x5/43/

```
var item = {};
item.elem = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(item.elem);
item.addEvent = function(name,listener) {
    var wrappedListener = function() {
        //Access the scope through the callee properties.
        return listener.apply( arguments.callee.scope, arguments);
    }
    addEvent(this.elem,name,wrappedListener);
    //Save the scope not as a closure, but as a property on the handler.
    wrappedListener.scope = this
    return wrappedListener;
}
var wrap = item.addEvent('eventName',listen);
removeEvent(item.elem, 'eventName', wrap);
//Force the circular reference to GO AWAY.
wrap.scope = null
if (item.elem.parentNode) {
    item.elem.parentNode.removeChild(item.elem);
}
//item.elem = null; //No longer needed.
```

Comment: I know that IE used to have a bug where it would use separate garbage collection for native objects and javascript objects, so any time you form a cycle between javascript objects and native objects, neither garbage collector could clean it up.  Could that be it?  I'm thinking that item points to item.elem which is a div that has handlers that refer back to item.

Comment: — Not really pertinent to your question, but you can eliminate the `self` variable by using `listener.apply(item, arguments)` instead.  :-)

Comment: Totally! But this is actaully a much simplified version of a class that I wrote where the addEvent method does not have access to the instance so conveniently - hence var self = this

Comment: Opening post has been updated with a solution to the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the events (as almost always in Internet Explorer, BTW).

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/rJ8x5/39/ and notice how it garbage collects fine.

You are creating circular references when you attach the events. Read more about it in *[Circular references to DOM objects on an HTML page cause a memory leak](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830555)*.

Comment: Ah!  Yes, because the function traps a reference to the DOM element in the closure, and so when it's garbage collected by JScript the DOM element leaks.  Is that right?

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, it's all about scoping of the event handler, or rather about the DOM references trapped in that scope :)

Comment: I am aware of IE's circular reference related memory leaks. The point here, however, is the I am specifically _removing_ the event handler. Should this not break the circular reference?

Comment: @jordancpaul: For some reason ie doesn't understand that it is ok to garbage collect the handler, or more specifically it's scope when you have removed it. This has been the way in ie for a long time... read this for kicks: http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html

Comment: I have updated my original post with additional comments that better illustrate why I am confused.

Comment: @jordan: i think crockford explains it pretty well in the following line: `The JavaScript garbage collector understands about cycles and is not confused by them. Unfortunately, IE's DOM is not managed by JScript. It has its own memory manager that does not understand about cycles and so gets very confused. As a result, when cycles occur, memory reclamation does not occur.` Once the cyclic reference has been there, the GC gets stuck and you have to explicitly tell it to free stuff by nulling it. I agree it shouldn't be that way, but it is.

Comment: If it is true that there is no way to free up scope of a detached handler then even though I have set item.elem = null, there will still (and forever) be lost memory due to the overhead of item.

Comment: But there is no longer a cycle here. It would make sense to me if a handler had an element in it's scope and an element had that handler attached - this could cause the problem that Crockford describes. However that is not the case in this scenario - I have removed the handler...

Comment: Cave At: As i have not been part in making ie, and thus doesn't know the inner working of it from anything but many years experience/observation, there is a chance that i am missing something :)

Comment: Well further reading on Douglas Crockfords site led me to read this:
`Note that handlers that were added with attachEvent() will not be found and will continue to leak.`
I thought about the problem a bit further and came up with a workaround. I have updated the post to reflect this

Comment: @jordancpaul: you can also read more on ie leaks patterns here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb250448.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The code leaks because you are calling attachEvent improperly - Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) insists that the event name be a standard DHTML event.

If you change `'eventName'` to `'click'`, it does not leak.

A more robust solution would be to change your event attaching code to check `'on'+eventname in domElement` and refuse to attach the event if this is false.