# How do you cleanly remove DOM elements in Prototype JS?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, prototypejs

Say I have a container with various elements inside. In turn, any element could have various event listeners.

```
<div id="container">
   <video src="movie.mp4"></video>
   <a>Some button</a>
</div>
```

With Prototype JS, how do you properly remove each element and their event listeners from memory? The following is the explicit way to clean everything:

```
$('container').childElements().each(
   function(child) {
      Event.stopObserving(child);
      child.remove();
   }
);
```

The following is a much quicker way to clear the container:

```
$('container').update();
```

But will it cause memory leaks? Will most javascript engines understand that if I clear the innerHTML, I also want to clear the event listeners on each element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, event handlers will go away when the element goes away. Clearing the `innerHTML` of the container destroys all contained elements, thus the attached event handlers.

Older versions of Internet Explorer (<= IE8) have problems re-claiming memory from event handlers when the owning element was destroyed.  To accommodate them, you should use `Event.stopObserving`.

To be absolutely sure, you could extend `Element` like this:

```
Element.addMethods({
    clear: function(element) {
        element = $(element);

        element.descendants().each(function(elem) {
            Event.stopObserving(elem);
        });

        return element.update();
    }
});
```

This removes all events from all descendants before re-setting the element contents itself. It does not seem like `Event.stopObserving()` itself is recusive, so without that step there might still be leaks from elements "further down". Use it like this:

```
$('container').clear();
```

[See this as a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/Kn9NC/)

*Disclaimer: I am not familiar with prototype. If the above is incorrect, please leave a comment.*

Related reading:

- [Why does this leak in Internet Explorer 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903379/why-does-this-leak-in-internet-explorer-8)
- [Douglas Crockford on memory leaks in IE](http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html)

Comment: This does work with Prototype. Thanks Tomalak. I spent a few hours troubleshooting code, but this fixed my problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you will be regularly adding and removing elements within a stable container then it might save time and memory-worries if you use [`Event.on`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) instead.

```
$('container').on('click', 'a', function() {
    // button is clicked
});
```

This way the event handler is persistent regardless of the elements, and no new handlers are created so any leaks are not being fed.